# Navigator.pop not working and show black background?

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-layout, navigator

I try back to previous screen. But UI only show black background and it only happens on this screen. I tried both `Navigator.pop(context);` and `Navigator.of(context).pop();`.

This my code:

```
return MaterialApp(
    home: SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: BlocBuilder<TimeKeepingCubit, TimeKeepingState>(
    builder: (context, state)
{
  var scale = 1.0;
  if (state.controller != null){
    var camera = state.controller!.value;
    // fetch screen size
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    // calculate scale depending on screen and camera ratios
    // this is actually size.aspectRatio / (1 / camera.aspectRatio)
    // because camera preview size is received as landscape
    // but we're calculating for portrait orientation
    var scale = size.aspectRatio * camera.aspectRatio;

    // to prevent scaling down, invert the value
    if (scale < 1) scale = 1 / scale;
  }
  return Stack(
    children: [
      state.controller == null ? SizedBox() : Center(
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: scale,
          child: Center(
            child: CameraPreview(state.controller!),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Visibility(
        visible: state is TimeKeepingLoading,
        child: Center(
            child: Container(
                width: 68,
                height: 68,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: AppColors.whiteE0E0E0),
                child: CupertinoActivityIndicator())
        ),
      ),
      buildAlignScafoldScan(),
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(Res.ic_back_left_blue),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            // Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my problem. That's the context in this code

```
BlocBuilder<TimeKeepingCubit, TimeKeepingState>(
    builder: (context, state)
```

make when used `Navigator.pop(context);` inside it causes black screen. My solution was to create a function that scopes use `Navigator.pop(context);` is no longer in the `BlocBuilder`. It will use the `context` of the main screen.

```
void backToPreScreen() {
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UI shows black background when there is nowhere to go or pop within app. What page you want to go using pop? Instead of Navigator.pop() use `Navigator.push()` to the page you want to go onPress.

```
 onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondPage()),
        );
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see it is your `MaterialApp` where you are tryng to call `Navigator.pop(context)`. As this is the first screen on the stack both the `pop` methods will show a black screen. You can only pop when there are other screens below. Let's say there are 2 screens. You should use `Navigator.push` when calling screen2 from screen1 and call `Navigator.pop(context)` on the screen2 to get back to the screen1. If screen1 is your first and only screen then popping it would result into balck screen.